# Why adding large resource to an exe is slow and sometimes corrupts the exe?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am trying out different features of the Madres unit from Mad-collections (a unit for adding/deleting or updating resources in an exe) in my own code. This works fine for small resources (less than 50 MB) but often fails for larger resources (bigger than 50 MB).

The major problem with the code below is: the application freezes for minutes, and sometimes it crashes and creates a corrupted exe.

Can anyone suggest a better approach to tackle this problem?

```
//add resource
procedure UpdateExeResource(Const Source,Dest:string);
var
  Stream     : TFileStream;
  hDestRes   : DWORD;
  lpData     : Pointer;
  cbData     : DWORD;
begin
  Stream := TFileStream.Create(Source,fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
  try
    Stream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
    cbData:=Stream.Size;
    if cbData>0 then
    begin
      GetMem(lpData,cbData);
      try
        Stream.Read(lpData^, cbData);
        hDestRes:= BeginUpdateResourceW(PChar(Dest), False);
        if hDestRes <> 0 then

          if UpdateResourceW(hDestRes, RT_RCDATA,'DATA',0,lpData,cbData) then
          begin
            if not EndUpdateResourceW(hDestRes,FALSE) then RaiseLastOSError
          end
          else
          RaiseLastOSError
        else
        RaiseLastOSError;
      finally
        FreeMem(lpData);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;

//Add or update resource
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  UpdateExeResource('asd.txt', 'copy.exe');
end;
```

Comment: If this is MadExcept code, did you ask on Madshis'forum? http://forum.madshi.net/viewforum.php?f=4

Comment: this is a custom code, but uses madres

Comment: The code here does not use madres. It uses raw Win32. Is your virus scanner getting in the way? What happens when you switch it off.

Comment: it seems, my code uses madres. I have added the madres unit to my application, moreover, when i click on 'UpdateResourceW' it takes me to madres unit.

Comment: OK, I understand now. These functions have the same interface as the Win32 functions, but are implemented by Mathias. What did he say when you asked on his forum?

Comment: Off topic, but your share mode is wrong. You want `fmShareDenyWrite`. Also, I'd use a memory stream to load the file. Create memory stream, call `LoadFromFile`, and then pass the pointer to the memory to `UpdateResourceW`.

Comment: I just added FASTMM4 unit to my project and the performance has tremendously improved. 
Another issue i have observed is: suppose i have added a 50 MB avi file to my exe, adding resource works fine - but when i try to run the new exe it take around 15-20 seconds to load. I understand that exe with 50MB resource will need time to load.. :( Is there any technique to improve this load time
?

Comment: the technique is not putting an AVI file into an executable as a resource and if you must then compress it before and uncompress it after I guess using some crazy algorithm ^^

Comment: @jimsweb: Theoretically, Windows can page parts of an .exe into memory on demand as needed -- so a large resource shouldn't affect program load at all, until the resource is loaded.  Practically, your virus scanner is going to scan the entire .exe before letting Windows do that, so don't embed extra resources into your exe unless there's a really good reason for it, and keep them small if you do.  Digitally signed executables are also scanned in their entirety as well when the signature is verified -- I don't know if or when Windows does this automatically.

Comment: And ideally you should always strive towards making the executable file as small as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your reasoning for using Madres unit which is nothing more then a spoof of the Windows API call functions [BeginUpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648030%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [UpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [EndUpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in order to add support for the  old Windows 9x family(Win95,98,ME).

I suggest you modify your procedure (properly) to reference the actual *Winapi.Windows* function calls either by removing Madres unit from uses section or adding a prefix to the function when you call it like this :

```
  Winapi.Windows.BeginUpdateResourceW(...);
  Winapi.Windows.UpdateResourceW(...);
  Winapi.Windows.EndUpdateResourceW(...);
```

If support for the 9x family is what you need then just create a seperate method for using the Madres api calls and use it when it's actually necessary.

Also note that UpdateResourceW expects it's string parameters to be in Unicode format.

Comment: As per madres help:
The NT APIs aren't as reliable as you might think, either. If you use the resource update APIs on a Delphi binary, which has TD32 debug infos in it, the binary is totally invalid afterwards. Windows doesn't even recognize it as a valid PE file anymore. Another disadvantage of the NT resource update APIs is that the size of the resource section is often not adjusted, if you remove resources. So your binary is bigger than it has to be. - this is the reason i am sticking with madres

Comment: Windows API ResourceUpdate method has no problem updating resources in a "Delphi" binary executable file, the only reason you are getting a corrupted binary is because you've incorrectly used thus functions, refer to the hyperlinks or search for example implementation of Win Api UpdateResource method.

Comment: `UpdateResourceW` does not expect Unicode formatted data. It expects its parameters to be Unicode strings rather than ANSI strings. The data is the data. You can write Unicode encoded data with `UpdateResourceA` if you want. You just can't give the resource a Unicode name.

Comment: @Nortd: your suggestion works fine if compile my application in release mode - i.e. without any debug information